# Incorrect Extent when importing images into ArcMap 10.7

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, extents

I have 2 JPG images of the same pixel size and of the same square mile area, with identical JGW and aux.xml files. One displays correctly, the second does not.

I am stumped, and it seems that ESRI support is stumped. Over the course of a year, we generate about 200K annotated files, so we need a clean way to generate the world and aux files and any others needed to allow display of rectified images, without having our customers having to re-project, recalculate etc. Our software currently generates these files and we think the data and format is correct.

I have a workflow that does the following

We ortho raw data through ArcGISPro and develop a mosaic. Input is IMGxxxx.jpg and a csv file with the IMU data.

We generate a mosaic using arcgispro, then export the mosaic to JPG tiles.  Sample Name is KE192_26.JPG

We send these images to our remote analysts, who annotate the images with yellow squares using PhotoShop. Our .net software scans the images, assigns a target ID for each yellow square, adds the target ID to the image, saves the modified image, and records some tabular data in a csv file. Sample Name is KE192_26_Out.JPG

I have tried loading these 2 files into ArcMap 10.7.0 Both images have spatial reference as seen in the layer Properties (NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_11N)

Only the first (KE192_26.JPG) tile correctly loads with the correct extent values.

The annotated file (KE192_26_Out.JPG) has incorrect extents, although the world and aux.xml files are the same for the 2 images.

Here is the world file:

0.1055822640

0.0000000000

0.0000000000

-0.1055822640

293828.4972528925

3931418.2711116746

And the aux.xml (The first and last lines containing the PAMDataset tag will not display in the following text)

"
SRS>COMPD_CS["unknown",PROJCS["NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_11N",GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6269"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9102"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4269"]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator",AUTHORITY["Esri","43006"]],PARAMETER["False_Easting",500000.0,AUTHORITY["Esri","100001"]],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0,AUTHORITY["Esri","100002"]],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-117.0,AUTHORITY["Esri","100010"]],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996,AUTHORITY["Esri","100003"]],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0,AUTHORITY["Esri","100021"]],UNIT["Meter",1.0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","26911"]],VERTCS["NAVD_1988",VDATUM["North_American_Vertical_Datum_1988",AUTHORITY["EPSG","5103"]],PARAMETER["Vertical_Shift",0.0,AUTHORITY["Esri","100006"]],PARAMETER["Direction",1.0,AUTHORITY["Esri","100007"]],UNIT["Meter",1.0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","5703"]]]
"

Comment: Too much unnecessary information, but critical bit is missing. One does not displaying correctly? Is it smaller? In the middle of nowhere?

Comment: @FelixIP Thanks for the nudge - It appeared to be somewhere in the South Pacific, So I realized that I had not copied and renamed the JGw file. Did so and the images are now in the same place. Even better the snippet is correctly located when I copied the JGw file for the snippet - which says I have an error in the manufactured JGw file. Thanks again - I'll close this question!

Answer (score 2):

The test directory did not have corresponding JGW file for the image that was incorrectly located. Added these to the directory and the issue was resolved

Comment: +1 for efforts. My suspicion was Photoshop messing image dimensions, rows, columns

Comment: @FelixIP Thanks - The tiles were generated from ArcGISPro. PS did not alter the size, pixel count, not any EXIF data, just RGB values of a few pixels. The same JGw and aux.xml should work for both. I have created the JGw and aux.xml files for the extracted 1000x1500 snippets, and after correcting for 2 minor syntax errors, still cannot get ArcMap to recognize the projection, even though Notepad++ says the files are the same as those for the large images. ArcMap does not report errors in the formatting or content of these files, except for a note that there is no projection data available.

Comment: I'd keep world file, remove aux and redefine projection in batch.

Comment: @FelixIP Thanks for the suggestion - we generate about 150,000 of these each year for about 50 customers of all sizes, and their staff are not ArcMap techies - and versions are all over the place. So we need a way that lets the customers download the data and use without effort. We have .net software that allows them to used the data outside of ArcMAp and this is an attempt to get a better integration with the other uses they have for ArcMap - such as profiling infestations and looking at current conditions of past  targets. Thx - Bob